# The Ghostly Answer

Tags: bug

I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143787/editing-lines-in-an-existing-file) question a few minutes ago, and a thingy popped up that said

```
                              1 new answer to this question
```

I was busy at that moment, so I didn't load the answer immediately. When I did, though:

> [image]
>   <sub>Notice the distinct lack of answers</sub>

<strike>I ran from the room, screaming in terror at the phantom answer.</strike> After refreshing the page, it disappeared:

> [image]
>   <sub>Notice the distinct lack of answers</sub>

I assume that it was an answer that got deleted before I loaded it.

Comment: It shows how deeply ingrained behaviour it is that I tried to click on "1 new answer to this question" at the top of your question

Comment: @RichardTingle: I keep hitting the [`F` key](http://stackapps.com/questions/2567/official-keyboard-shortcuts)..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I assume that it was an answer that got deleted before I loaded it.

Your assumption is correct, there is a deleted answer on that question, deleted within 1 minute of posting, by the author.

It was an incorrect answer, the author received a comment pointing out the error and it was deleted again. I see no point in posting a screenshot here to embarrass the author any further.

Answer (score 0):

Comment: this is creepy!